# Actions for UIButtons in UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I implemented a UIButton in every cell of my UITableView and set an action for this button. Now I'm trying to find out which of these buttons was tapped:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    <...>

    UIButton *but=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    but.frame= CGRectMake(275, 5, 40, cell.frame.size.height-10);
    [but setTitle:@"Map" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [but addTarget:self action:@selector(Map:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:but];

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    return cell;

}

- (IBAction) Map: (id) sender {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] init];
    indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell*)[[sender superview]superview]];
    [delegate callMap: [[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] 
                         objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+1] 
                        objectAtIndex:kNameInArray]

                     : [[[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] 
                          objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+1] 
                         objectAtIndex:kXcoordinateInArray] doubleValue]

                     : [[[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] 
                          objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+1] 
                         objectAtIndex:kYcoordinateInArray] doubleValue]
     ];
}
```

But it always sends `data[0][1][*]` elements to the delegate. I mean `indexPath` always has 0 raw and 0 section. Where is my mistake?

Comment: I don't think you need to alloc an NSIndexPath here:

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] init];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following:
add the button inside your `if (cell == nil) { ... }` method or else you will have lots of buttons inside the same cell when your cell is reused.

Set `cell.contentViow.tag = SomeValueIdentifyingYourData` (some int value representing your model.. maybe just the index of your object array..) before returning the cell.

Inside your `Map:` method you can access the value again with `((UIButton)sender).superview.tag` and make your decisions based on that value

Comment: that worked for me, Now I know what button pressed, but it something wrong with displaying button if do just like you say: it skucks under some another view, so only part (few pixels at the right side) of it shows up.

Comment: experiment with frame and autoresizing masks :)